# Python Json match on exact key

Tags: python, json, key

I am new to Python.

I'm processing a json response where I will act on the "user_id" key of each result. Some results don't have a "user_id" key, so I must check that they do, before I act, or move on to the next result.  The problem I'm having is that there are other keys that have 'user_id' as part of their name.

```
{
    }, 
    "results": [
        {
            "favorite_user_id": null, 
            "creation_tsz": 1425492797, 
            "target_user_id": 57182221
        }, 
        {
            "favorite_user_id": null, 
            "user_id": 57021365, 
            "creation_tsz": 1424864160, 
            "target_user_id": 57182221
        }, 
        {
            "favorite_user_id": null, 
            "user_id": 31767074, 
            "creation_tsz": 1424728865, 
            "target_user_id": 57182221
        },
```

and so on...

I've been using this check:

```
for result in response_json["results"]:
    if 'user_id' in result:
```

But that produces false positives as it finds the other keys that contain user_id (like target_user_id).  So I need to perform this test for the 'user_id' key as either an exact match, or a 'starts with' match as the other keys that contain 'user_id' always have it at the end of the key name.

I've read lots of answers here about matching this way, but figuring out how to do it in this test has be stumped.

Thanks for the help.

On request, here are the contents of r.content and r.json()"

r.content below
{"count":33,"results":[{"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1425492797},{"user_id":57021365,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424864160},{"user_id":31767074,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424728865},{"user_id":39870895,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424708778},{"user_id":11096738,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424706888},{"user_id":23567712,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424699725},{"user_id":33175317,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424677405},{"user_id":34755908,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424675524},{"user_id":41899895,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424666480},{"user_id":45411514,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424664682},{"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424647475},{"user_id":8656711,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424645878},{"user_id":8054406,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424643341},{"user_id":52539991,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424543725},{"user_id":25719102,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424543406},{"user_id":29287388,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424503218},{"user_id":32826696,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424492383},{"user_id":30241548,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424443367},{"user_id":31395992,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424437914},{"user_id":22811743,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424436983},{"user_id":24661450,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424419158},{"user_id":52909867,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424412474},{"user_id":20872810,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424404944},{"user_id":8023509,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424395275},{"user_id":55397081,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424388386},{"user_id":39617646,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424384861},{"user_id":32033901,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424379711},{"user_id":11525852,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424376963},{"user_id":17015110,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1424356740},{"user_id":35905186,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1423059122},{"user_id":60537493,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1422298901},{"user_id":22852591,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1421247342},{"user_id":54391049,"favorite_user_id":null,"target_user_id":57182221,"creation_tsz":1420559950}],"params":{"user_id":"lukectracy","limit":"100","offset":0,"page":null},"type":"FavoriteUser","pagination":{"effective_limit":100,"effective_offset":0,"next_offset":null,"effective_page":1,"next_page":null}}

r.json() content below
{u'count': 33, u'type': u'FavoriteUser', u'pagination': {u'effective_limit': 100, u'effective_page': 1, u'next_page': None, u'effective_offset': 0, u'next_offset': None}, u'params': {u'limit': u'100', u'user_id': u'lukectracy', u'page': None, u'offset': 0}, u'results': [{u'favorite_user_id': None, u'creation_tsz': 1425492797, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 57021365, u'creation_tsz': 1424864160, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 31767074, u'creation_tsz': 1424728865, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 39870895, u'creation_tsz': 1424708778, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 11096738, u'creation_tsz': 1424706888, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 23567712, u'creation_tsz': 1424699725, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 33175317, u'creation_tsz': 1424677405, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 34755908, u'creation_tsz': 1424675524, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 41899895, u'creation_tsz': 1424666480, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 45411514, u'creation_tsz': 1424664682, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'creation_tsz': 1424647475, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 8656711, u'creation_tsz': 1424645878, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 8054406, u'creation_tsz': 1424643341, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 52539991, u'creation_tsz': 1424543725, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 25719102, u'creation_tsz': 1424543406, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 29287388, u'creation_tsz': 1424503218, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 32826696, u'creation_tsz': 1424492383, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 30241548, u'creation_tsz': 1424443367, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 31395992, u'creation_tsz': 1424437914, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 22811743, u'creation_tsz': 1424436983, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 24661450, u'creation_tsz': 1424419158, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 52909867, u'creation_tsz': 1424412474, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 20872810, u'creation_tsz': 1424404944, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 8023509, u'creation_tsz': 1424395275, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 55397081, u'creation_tsz': 1424388386, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 39617646, u'creation_tsz': 1424384861, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 32033901, u'creation_tsz': 1424379711, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 11525852, u'creation_tsz': 1424376963, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 17015110, u'creation_tsz': 1424356740, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 35905186, u'creation_tsz': 1423059122, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 60537493, u'creation_tsz': 1422298901, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 22852591, u'creation_tsz': 1421247342, u'target_user_id': 57182221}, {u'favorite_user_id': None, u'user_id': 54391049, u'creation_tsz': 1420559950, u'target_user_id': 57182221}]}

Comment: The example of `results` you've provided is from Javascript, Python does not have `null`. Is the problem that you have not parsed the JSON with Python?

Comment: I process it first.  "response_json = r.json()."  The null isn't involved in my issue from what I can tell.

Comment: Unless you have defined a variable `null` somewhere in your python script, that is not valid python. Try this: `d = {"favorite_user_id": null}`. Result is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined`

Comment: I produced the sample of the json data using json.dumps(repsonse_json, indent=4).  I don't understand how that would output value of null if it were not valid json.  it's not a variable, it's a value.

Comment: It _is_ valid JSON, it's _not_ valid python. Your question really isn't about JSON, it's about working with certain data structures in python. I would prefer to see the result of just `print`ing the value from python.

Answer (score 1):

Stop iterating over the keys. Containment checking on a mapping compares keys.

```
if 'user_id' in response_json["results"]:
```

Comment: That's a good shortcut to how I was doing it, thanks.  But it produces the same result.  When I act on response_json["user_id"] inside this if, it generates a 'KeyError: 'user_id'', because the entry it's acting on doesn't have that key, despite passing the if statement.

Comment: ... That's because it would be `response_json["results"]["user_id"]`.

Comment: I'm using result["user_id"].  It works when manually bypass the entry without a user_id.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is you're handling your JSON as a string still. It will be a lot easier to work with if you decode it into structured data first:

```
import json
jdata = json.loads(response_json)
for result in jdata:
    if result.has_key('user_id'):
        # and so on...
```

Comment: The 'jdata = ' generates an error  'TypeError: expected string or buffer'.

Comment: OK, so `response_json` is not a string. But then I'm at a loss to explain that searching for 'user_id' matches 'favorite_user_id'. It would be helpful if you'd post more of the code so we can see what we're actually working with here.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that you have somehow converted your JSON "responses" into a Python list, but that the dict-type values inside that list are still encoded as strings. If this is the case, the problem is not in the code that's failing, but upstream in how you're decoding your JSON.  It would be helpful to trace exactly where `response_json` comes from. Also, is this running standalone or as part of a Django, Flask, etc. environment?

Comment: This is running standalone.  I think the relevant lines that show where response_json comes from are the following:

`import requests, json
from json import JSONEncoder

r = requests.get(url, params=userspayload, headers=usersheaders)
response_json = r.json()

for result in response_json:
    if result.has_key('user_id'):`

It's a fairly small script so I'm thinking we aren't too far from solving this.   Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: OK, so you're using the json method of the Requests request object. That *should* decode just fine. Could you print r.content and r.json() and update your question to show the results of each? Or some de-identified form that shows the formatting of each?

Comment: @LukeTracy Looks like you're decoding just fine. But looking at other comments, it looks like the question may have changed. It now seems like you want to know how to look for a dict key that might or might not be present. Just skip the `jdata=` part of my answer and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior your describing seems to indicate you're working with a string, not a dict, checking to see if the string `result` contained the string `user_id`.

```
# We don't want to match this:
result = 'junk___user_id___junk'
'user_id' in result   # True
'user_id' == result   # False

# We __do__ want to match this:
result = 'user_id'                                                                                                                                                                     
'user_id' in result   # True
'user_id' == result   # True
```

Look what happens when with a dictionary, it behaves as you expect:

```
good_dict = {'user_id': True}
bad_dict = {'bad_user_id': True}
'user_id' in good_dict   # True
'user_id' in bad_dict    # False
```

Have you parsed the json with a json parsing library? Are you dealing with real python dicts or are you working with strings?

Comment: I process the raw response (r) with response_json = r.json().